# Vim highlighting trailing white space after certain movements with coloscheme

Tags: vim

#### Problem

After setting a colorscheme in Vim, (following the proscribed method of moving the colorscheme.vim file to ~/.vim/colors), and performing multi-line movements such as Ctrl-D/Ctrl-U for Page Up/Down, Vim highlights some to all of the trailing white space. You can see what I'm seeing with this image:

[image: Improper highlighting in Vim]]

I've noticed similar behavior with other movements, such as "100j/k" to move a large amount of lines. After the error is triggered, more movement seems to aggravate the issue. Smaller movements don't seem to do anything until they start moving the screen.

#### Attempted

Installing different colorschemes to check if it was scheme specific, trying Vim in a Vagrant box to see if it was my computer.

Searching Google, Stack Overflow, Super User--finding surprisingly nothing similar.

#### Environment

Windows 10 on Surface Pro. 
Using Ubuntu Bash on Windows (WSL).
Vim 8.0.
Tried with molokai.vim and rigel.vim colorschemes.
Here's my vimrc:

```
set ruler
set number
set textwidth=80

" Creates tabs:
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab " whether tabs are tabs or spaces
set autoindent

syntax enable
set wildmenu " visual autocomplete menu <tab>/<alt-tab> to cycle
set incsearch " search as characters are entered
set hlsearch " highlights search results
" turn off search highlight, since it persists, with: \<space>
nnoremap <leader><space> :nohlsearch<CR>
colorscheme rigel
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but it might help others.
I solved this issue by removing this line from my vimrc:

```
set listchars=nbsp:█,eol:¶,tab:>-,extends:»,precedes:«,trail:•
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this answer on an other post, I had the same problem and it wasn't due to the listchars option. This solved everything :
Add `autocmd VimEnter * set t_ut= to your vimrc file` .

Answer (score 0):

This was the first thread I saw when trying to fix the same issue, so I thought it would be a good idea to update this question with what worked for me.

It seemed that my vim color scheme was giving way to my terminal (kitty) color scheme as I scrolled down the page. Luckily, [I stumbled upon a GitHub issue for kitty](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/108).

Adding the following to my `.vimrc` fixed the issue for me.

```
" vim hardcodes background color erase even if the terminfo file does
" not contain bce (not to mention that libvte based terminals
" incorrectly contain bce in their terminfo files). This causes
" incorrect background rendering when using a color theme with a
" background color.
let &t_ut=''
```